# Connecting to Fly.io Postgres from Vercel

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma, vercel, fly

Is it possible possible to connect to Fly.io Postgres from a NEXT.js API route served from a Vercel severless function, and if so, *how*?

I've read and reread the [Fly.io Postgres docs](https://fly.io/docs/postgres/), focusing especially on [Connecting from outside Fly.io](https://fly.io/docs/postgres/#connecting-to-postgres-from-outside-fly) and (since my API routes use Prisma to connect to Postgres) [Connecting with Prisma](https://fly.io/docs/postgres/#connecting-with-prisma-node-js-docs), but it seems I would need to either install flyctl or a set up a WireGuard Tunnel in Vercel, neither of which I could figure out how to do from web searches.

I found essentially [the same question](https://community.fly.io/t/fly-poostgres-with-vercel-app/7444) on the Fly.io community forum, but unfortunately, no one has answered it after 26 days (as of this writing).

To add a bit more detail, I'm familiar with Heroku Postgres, where a connection string is essentially all that's needed to connect, but it seems connecting to Fly.io Postgres requires a connection string *plus* a proxy created with flyctl. This was easy to get working on my local machine, but it's not clear how to do this on a remote host like Vercel.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to allocate an ip address to your app with [link here](https://fly.io/docs/postgres/connecting/connecting-external/#allocate-an-ip-address)

```
fly ips allocate-v4 --app <pg-app-name>
```

Then add these service configurations to the fly.toml file

```
[[services]]
 internal_port = 5432 # Postgres instance
 protocol = "tcp"

[[services.ports]]
 handlers = ["pg_tls"]
 port = 5432
```

Redeploy your app with `fly deploy`

Go to your fly dashboard you will be able to see  Ip Addresses that you can use as `host` to connect to the database